# Scrapy - Good way to split exported files?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I want to split the files exported by the JsonLinesItemExporter into multiple files
whenever the spider has parsed a certain number of items (MAX_ITEMS).
The code below is a working solution, but I need some input on the approach here. I fear
that something might go wrong at some point as I'm explicitly calling spider_opened() and spider_closed() to close the old file and open a new one. Any ideas/best practices are appreciated :)

```
# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/item-pipeline.html

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import JsonLinesItemExporter

MAX_ITEMS = 10000
class DmozPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

class JsonLinePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}
        self.ids_seen = set()
        self.fileid = 0
        self.filetype = ".json"

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open("items-" + str(self.fileid) + self.filetype, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = JsonLinesItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        i = len(self.ids_seen)
        if i % MAX_ITEMS + 1 == True and i > 0:
            self.spider_closed(spider)
            self.fileid = self.fileid + 1
            self.spider_opened(spider)

        if item['link'][0] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate site found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['link'][0])
            self.exporter.export_item(item)
            return item
```

Answer (score 0):

old question, but for the sake of completeness:

There is the  FEED_EXPORT_BATCH_ITEM_COUNT option.

in the settings.py (or equivalent) use:
FEED_EXPORT_BATCH_ITEM_COUNT = 100

And your crawl command line is:

scrapy crawl spidername -o "dirname/%(batch_id)d-filename%(batch_time)s.json"

see [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std-setting-FEED_EXPORT_BATCH_ITEM_COUNT)